# : wasm validation error: at offset 8: binary version 0x1 does not match expected version 0xd index.html:31:24

Tags: c, webassembly

When I compile C code to wasm using emcc, I get this error information in firefox javascript console:

```
: wasm validation error: at offset 8: binary version 0x1 does not match expected version 0xd  index.html:31:24
```

I don't know what lead to this error. Could you please explain it to me?

Comment: Please more information on the server side code.

Comment: `emcc hello.c -Os -s WASM=1 -s SIDE_MODULE=1 -o hello.wasm`
This is my command.
In hello.c:
`#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  printf("Hello World\n");
}`

Comment: [https://mdn.github.io/webassembly-examples/js-api-examples/index.html](https://mdn.github.io/webassembly-examples/js-api-examples/index.html)
also have this error information in firefox javascript console.

Comment: Oh, by the way, I used Firefox Developer Edition.

Comment: @JiangXuan please add that additional information [into your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42592318/edit).

Comment: I hope you are OK with my edits. While you are obviously not a native speaker, your English is plenty good enough where you don't need to apologize for it.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Thanks for your improve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered your question [on github](https://github.com/WebAssembly/website/issues/79) already, reposting here.

---

> I am China boy is not good at english, please don't keep in mind if i said something wrong.

Your language is perfectly fine, no need to apologize! Many of us are also non-native English speakers

---

I believe the problem you're running into is that WebAssembly [is moving to version 1](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-webassembly/2017Feb/0002.html). Older toolchains and browsers expected version `0xD` as a pre-release thing. They now expect version `0x1`.

You're therefore hitting the transition period between pre-release and initial-release. Your browser is behind the toolchain you're using.

Can you specify which browser version you're using, and which toolchain version you're using? Not just "developer edition" but the exact release information.

The problem will resolve itself as everything gets updated to the released version. This is an unfortunate side-effect of the initial release.

binaryen was updated to `0x1` in [this commit](https://github.com/WebAssembly/binaryen/pull/913). From this you can work back which binaryen version you have. Emscripten brought that version into its `incoming` branch with [this commit](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/pull/4953). You'll need to use its incoming branch at least after this commit to get `0x1` binaries, which is labeled as 1.37.3. earlier Emscripten will produce `0xD` binaries.

Browsers will update the same way. If Firefox developer edition expects `0xD` then try Nightly. In this transitional case it may be easier to change toolchains or browser version to match.

Answer (score 0):

I met the reversed problem and I fixed very fast in JS: 
After file fetching I got the buffer to whom I did:

```
new Int32Array(buffer​,4,4)[0]=1 //or 13 in your case
```

This solution is only for this​ transition which changes​ only the version number but not the structure.