# How to check the WebAssembly version of a wasm binary

Tags: module, versioning, webassembly

**Given a `.wasm` file how can I check [the version of the binary encoding](http://webassembly.org/docs/binary-encoding/#high-level-structure)?**

---

I have been trying to experiment with WebAssembly but have started to encounter what I understand to be versioning issues resulting in messages such as:

> Error: Wasm.instantiateModule(): Wasm decoding failedResult = expected version 0c 00 00 00, found 0b 00 00 00 @+4

or

> Error: Wasm.instantiateModule(): Wasm decoding failedResult = expected version 0c 00 00 00, found 01 00 00 00 @+4

Other than running it against a WebAssembly embedder that does not support a given file to get the above error, how can I check the version of a wasm file?

---

Edit:  According to the recent release notes, this is a time-limited issue, [going forward the version for all assemblies will `0x1`](http://webassembly.org/roadmap/#changes-since-the-browser-preview).

Comment: Right, this problem should only occur with pre-release versions of Wasm.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [: wasm validation error: at offset 8: binary version 0x1 does not match expected version 0xd index.html:31:24](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42592318/wasm-validation-error-at-offset-8-binary-version-0x1-does-not-match-expected)

Comment: @JFBastien Not a duplicate. That question wants to know the cause of the error and how to fix it.  This question wants to know, "given a `wasm` file what is the version of that file?"

Comment: @vossad01 at this point in time, getting a producer or consumer which generates or expects anything else than version 0x1 is a bug. The linked question answers causes of that bug.

Comment: @JFBastien From the perspective of the latest spec it is non-complaint and thus a bug; however, I doubt all the people who provided pre-MVP WebAssembly support in their software and all the people who wrote articles and guides with the tools available at the time would agree their work is "a bug."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have a hexdump utility you can look at the bytes 4-7 bytes of the file. For example, with the Linux hexdump utility:

```
$ hexdump -C -n8 examples_c/hello_sdl.wasm | head
00000000  00 61 73 6d 01 00 00 00                           |.asm....|
00000008
```

The first four bytes are the wasm magic number (0x0061736d or '\00asm'). The next 4 bytes are the version (little endian). So in the example above the version is 0x01 which is MVP (Minimum Viable Product).

At some point I'm sure the standard linux `file` command will identify WebAssembly files and print the version.

The full format is described in the [WebAssembly binary encoding page](https://github.com/WebAssembly/design/blob/master/BinaryEncoding.md).

Comment: Cool, a command I didn't know I had.  I half expected to need to pull out a scripting language to read the bytes.